# Constructing cut-off function on geodesic ball

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a complete non compact Riemannian manifold, $p \in M$ be a fixed point, $r > 0$ be an arbitrary (as large as one may want it to be) constant and $B_r(p) = \exp(B_r(0))$ the geodesic ball centered at $p$ of radius $r$. My goal is to prove the existence of a smooth function $\psi: M \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\psi = 1$ at $B_p(r)$, $\psi = 0$ outside of $B_p(2r)$ and $\|\nabla \psi\| \leq \frac{C}{R}$ for some constant $C > 0$. [As seen here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3787422/derivative-of-distance-function-on-a-riemannian-manifold), if we take a bump function $\phi: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\phi = 1$ in $[0, 1]$, $\phi = 0$ in $[2, \infty)$ and $\|\phi'\| \leq C$ on $[1, 2]$  and define $$\psi(x) = \phi\left(\frac{\text{dist}(x, p)}{r} \right)$$
Then we have that $\psi$ is smooth both at $B_p(r)$ and $M \setminus B_p(2r)$ (since it is constant there), is $1$ at the ball of radius $r$ and $0$ outside the ball of radius $2r$. And if $x$ is sufficiently close to $p$ (i.e, in a normal neighbourhood of $p$), we also have that $\|\nabla \psi\| \leq \frac{C}{R}$, as desired. This has been proven in the question I linked, which makes use of normal coordinates in a crucial manner.

However, I struggle to see how I can deal with points far away from $p$ (i.e, at a distance greater than the injectivity radius at $p$)? As far as I know, there is no reason $\psi$ has to even be smooth at $B_p(2r) \setminus B_p(r)$ (which is the only place we need to do the calculations since $\psi$ is constant elsewhere).  I'm asking this question because as I said, the answers in the question I linked make crucial use of normal coordinates and therefore don't address this problem.

I had an idea to fix the issue but I haven't been able to conclude it properly. Since the question I linked does prove (once you use extensions via bump functions) that there exist $r_0 > 0$ sufficiently small and $C > 0$  so that $\psi = 1$ at $B_p(r_0)$, $\psi = 0$ outside of $B_p(2 r_0)$ and $\|\nabla \psi \| \leq \frac{C}{r_0}$, if we find a smooth function $h : M \to M$ such that $h(B_p(r)) \subset B_p(r_0)$, $h(M \setminus B_p(2r)) \subset M \setminus B_p(2r_0) $ such that its differential has an appropriately bounded norm, we'll be done once we define $\tilde{\psi }= \psi \circ h$. But I'm struggling to find such an $h$ (I tried to define it via the exponential map but got into some troubles I couldn't solve).

So, how can I solve this problem? I'd appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** After searching some more I actually found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4207779/cut-off-function-on-complete-riemannian-manifolds) which basically completely solves my own question. But since I'd still welcome any different approaches (especially one that finished off my own), I'll leave my question up

Comment: This seems highly suspicious. What if $r$ is (slightly more than the diameter) of $M$?

Comment: @TedShifrin the diameter might not exist if $M$ is not compact. In the case the manifold is compact, then the statement doesn't really mean anything, so we can restrict ourselves to the non compact case

Comment: That was my point. Is non-compactness actually a hypothesis you omitted?

Comment: @TedShifrin It is indeed, thanks for pointing that out! I've had my head stuck on this for a while now and (wrongly) thought that would be implicit. I'll add it promptly

Comment: What about the answers in that post that completely avoid normal coordinates?

Comment: @TedShifrin the coordinate free way mentioned in the answer accepted in that post actually does (somewhat implicitly and in a very indirect manner, so to speak) use normal coordinates, since it doesn't make sense to talk about the gradient of the distance function at points in the cut locus (which might intersect the annulus $B_p(2r) \setminus B_p(r)$), because the distance function is not differentiable there. All the answers there face this same issue

Comment: Some quantifiers are missing here: How do you quantify $C$ and $R$? Also, keep in mind that the number $2$ in this solution is chosen arbitrarily. You can replace it with some number $>1$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I don't understand what's missing. $C$ is an arbitrary positive number whose existence is constructed in the proof (which is greater than $1$, as you said), and $R > 0$ is an arbitrary positive number.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Ah, I reviewed my question again and think I now see what you meant. I've edited my post accordingly.

Comment: Perhaps I'm just overlooking something, but I still don't see how noncompactnes ever comes up. The idea is that if we replace the gradient condition $\|\nabla\psi\|<C/R$ with a Lipschitz condition $\operatorname{Lip}(\psi)<C/R$, then the $\psi$ written in the question works full stop. Then the only issue is "smoothing out" the non-differentiabilities of $\psi$, and it turns out this can be done without changing $\operatorname{Lip}(\psi)$ by much. If the diameter of $M$ is small compared to $r$, then we may have $\psi=1$ or $\psi\neq 0$, but these still satisfy the hypotheses.

Comment: @Kajelad noncompactness is just to make sure the statement is never trivial, you're right that it doesn't really come up (adding it as a hypothesis is purely about esthetics imo). Because if $M$ is compact and $r$ is slightly more than its diameter, then the statement in particular guarantees the existence of a constant function on $M$ equal to $1$ everywhere on $M$ and $0$ at the empty set (whose gradient also obviously satisfies the desired estimate), which obviously always exists.